# Proxy Rewrite secure domain to insecure domain

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, url-rewriting, http-proxy-middleware

As I have created wordpress blog which is hosted in NGINX webserver, and this webserver is running on 8090 port and it is insecure. So to access blog post  I need to navigate as     http://example.org:8090/blog and http://example.org:8090/blog/wp-admin . and this both link were working fine at my end.But my requirement is to show those page contents from secure domain which is hosted in Node and it is a React based Application which is running on port 80 and 443 port so to make it work I have added [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware)  node proxy module.

**Work Around**

```
app.use('/blog', proxy('/blog', { target: 'http://example.org:8090', changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: { '^/blog': '' } }))   

app.use('/blog/wp-admin', proxy('/blog/wp-admin', { target: 'http://example.org:8090', changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: { '^/blog/wp-admin': '' } }))
```

But when I hit in url as https://example.org/blog it navigates to http://example.org:8090

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the documentation](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) - your `pathRewrite` option is removing the `/blog` prefix.

To map `/blog` to `/blog` and `/blog/wp-admin` to `/blog/wp-admin`, you do not need any `pathRewrite`, and you can achieve it using a single `app.use` statement.

Try:

```
app.use('/blog', proxy('/blog', { target: 'http://example.org:8090', changeOrigin: true }))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply let me try.

Comment: It is navigating but to old url with port number eg. http://example.org:8090/blog but I need blog to be get rendered as http://example.org/blog

Comment: Have you configured the SITEURL and HOME variables of the WordPress site? See [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) for more. You could use: `/blog` as the value if you want the site to work on both domains.

Comment: Still no luck added SITEURL and HOME

Comment: Thanks it works but now I am facing new issue as. contents  was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet

Comment: and same for js files